# Why Array and Integer constructor are ambigious

Tags: java

I have wrote this program in eclipse and eclipse is complaining that constructor is ambigious. I am not sure why java compiler calling them ambiguous.

```
public class Ambigious {

    public Ambigious(float[] a){
        System.out.println("array constructor");
    }


    public Ambigious(Integer a){
        System.out.println("Integer constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ambigious(null);
    }

}
```

but this is not

```
public class Ambigious {

    public Ambigious(Object a){
        System.out.println("object constructor");
    }

    public Ambigious(float[] a){
        System.out.println("array constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ambigious(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait, what are you asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem 1:
Both `float[]` and `Integer` are Objects so `null` can be applied to both constructors.

Since there isn't any *best suited type* compiler can't decide which one should be used.

Problem 2:
In case of `Object` and `Integer` types the most suited one is chosen. For instance if you would pass `new Integer(1)` as argument then both constructors could be applied because `Integer` is also `Object`, but compiler binds this invocation with code from constructor with most precise argument types.
Similarly with `null`, since it can be used as `Object` and `Integer` compiler assumes that the more precise type would be `Integer`.

---

To solve this kind of problems you can specify which type `null` should represent by casting

```
new Ambigious((Integer)null);
```

---

You can also try changing one of argument types to non-Object like

```
public Ambigious(int a){//primitive type
```

instead of

```
public Ambigious(Integer a){
```

Answer (score 3):

As the exception raised states, `reference to Ambigious is ambiguous, both constructor Ambigious(float[]) in Ambigious and constructor Ambigious(Integer) in Ambigious match`.

This means that both constructors can take the value you passed, which is `null`.